# Calling a Dialog From A Non Activity Class?

Tags: java, android

I am trying to call dialog from another class like this

```
public void alertbox() {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);    
    builder.setMessage("Blah").setCancelable(false);
    setNeutralButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                dialog.cancel();
            }
        }); 
    AlertDialog alert = builder.create(); alert.show();
}
```

I am calling this method from my class but my Application crashes, can someone tell me why?

Comment: You need `App context` for displaying this `Alert Dialog`. pass `context` to your `alertbox(context)`

Answer (score 2):

You need `Application context` for displaying this `Alert Dialog` from separate class. There are two ways to implement this.

1. Directly pass `context` to your `alertbox(context)` method
2. create a `single argument constructor` and passed `context` on it.

Here below i saw you second way pass `context` to `single argument constructor` like.

```
public class AlertMessages {
    Context context;

    public AlertMessages(Context con) {
        this.context=con;
    }

    public void alertbox() {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);            
        builder.setMessage("Blah")
                .setCancelable(false)
                .setNeutralButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() { 
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                            dialog.cancel();
                        }
                    }); 
        AlertDialog alert = builder.create(); 
        alert.show();
    } 
}
```

Then, use this `AlertMessages` class in your `Activity` like so:

```
AlertMessages msg = new AlertMessages(youractivity.this);
msg.alertbox();
```

Comment: but i want to call
AlertMessages msg = new AlertMessages(youractivity.this);
msg.alertbox();
from non activity class its not working

Comment: @AliJafar that is not possible. You must have App context for display AlertDialog.

Comment: So there is no other way to display dialog from Non activity class?

Comment: @AliJafar no no. I already told u you must have app context for displaying alert dialog.

Comment: So can i use FragmentDialog here? if yes so how can i use it ?

Answer (score -1):

use this form :

```
new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
.setTitle("MessageDemo")
.setMessage("eek!")
.setNeutralButton("Close", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
{
 public void onClick(DialogInterface dlg, int sumthin)
 {
  // do nothing – it will close on its own
 }
})
.show();
```

---

too :

As an alternate to supplying a view in onCreateView(), you can override
onCreateDialog() and supply a dialog instance.below codes supplies sample code for
this approach.

below codes. Overriding onCreateDialog() of a DialogFragment

```
MyDialogFragment
 {
    .....other functions
   @Override
   public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle icicle)
    {
       AlertDialog.Builder b = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
      .setTitle("My Dialog Title")
      .setPositiveButton("Ok", this)
      .setNegativeButton("Cancel", this)
      .setMessage(this.getMessage());
       return b.create();
    }
    .....other functions
 }
```

Comment: **it is not helpful** still i am not able to call dialog from non activity class